# SQL table Multiple rows for a id into multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to get data from 2 different tables and put the combined data into a report. Each claim number can have one of three possible statuses: approved, denied, appealed. An appeal can be either successful or denied.

Currently, each claim ID has multiple entries, but I want each claim grouped on a single record with each of the possible statuses as fields. Any ideas on best approach to get the output as below?

**Table 1**

```
Claim       AddDate     AddUser    
1234        08/01/2017  Catan    
4567        08/02/2017  Jigsu    
7890        08/07/2017  Panama
```

**Table 2**

```
Claim      Notes             NoteType
1234       Denied            2
1234       Appeal Success    3
4567       Approved          1
7890       Denied            2
7890       Appeal Denied     3
```

**OUTPUT TABLE**

```
Claim     ApprovalNote        DenialNote      AppealNote
1234      NULL                Denied          Appeal Success    
4567      Approved            NULL            NULL    
7890      NULL                Denied          Appeal Denied
```

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Use `Inner Join` in your case

Comment: I would recommend against keeping your data in that format. You are finding it does not lend itself well to parsing. Instead of a `Notes` field, you need to have dedicated fields for `Status` and `Appeal`. Then, look into using a `PIVOT` function.

Comment: @GaurangDeshpande - Inner joins gives me multiple records for 1234 and 7890 in final report. That is NOT what i am looking for.

Comment: @SandPiper - I agree. Unfortunately database design is a legacy design and in this case cannot be modified for sake of one report.

Answer (score 1):

You can join to each sub section of Table 2 to achieve this fairly painlessly without aggregation or case statements.

```
SELECT  
    t1.Claim ,
    ApprovalNote.Notes AS ApprovalNote ,
    DenialNote.Notes AS DenialNote ,
    AppealNote.Notes AS AppealNote
FROM    
    Table1 t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ApprovalNote 
        ON t1.Claim = ApprovalNote.Claim
        AND ApprovalNote.NoteType = 1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 DenialNote 
        ON t1.Claim = DenialNote.Claim
        AND DenialNote.NoteType = 2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 AppealNote 
        ON t1.Claim = AppealNote.Claim
        AND AppealNote.NoteType = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider conditional aggregation wrapped in an aggregate query:

```
SELECT m.Claim, Max(m.subApprovalNote) As ApprovalNote, 
                Max(m.subDenialNote) As DenialNote, 
                Max(m.subAppealNote) As AppealNote
FROM
   (SELECT t1.Claim, CASE WHEN t2.NoteType = 1
                          THEN t2.Notes
                          ELSE NULL
                     END AS subApprovalNote,
           CASE WHEN t2.NoteType = 2
                THEN t2.Notes
                ELSE NULL
           END AS subDenialNote,
           CASE WHEN t2.NoteType = 3
                THEN t2.Notes
                ELSE NULL
           END AS subAppealNote
    FROM table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.Claim = t2.Claim
   ) As m
GROUP BY m.Claim
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can try

```
Select claim ,
Case When exists (Select 1 from table2 where table1.claim = table2.claim 
                                         and notetype = 1
     Then 'Approved' Else Null End ,

Case When exists (Select 1 from table2 where table1.claim = table2.claim 
                                         and notetype = 2
     Then 'Denial' Else Null End ,


Case When exists (Select 1 from table2 where table1.claim = table2.claim 
                                         and notetype = 3 
     Then notes Else Null End 

from table1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
--Sample Data
declare @Table2 table(Claim int ,Notes varchar(500))
insert into @Table2
select 1234,'Denied' union
select 1234,'Appeal Success' union
select 4567,'Approved' union
select 7890,'Denied' union
select 7890,'Appeal Denied' 
--Main Query
SELECT Claim, 
[Approved] AS ApprovedNote,[Denied] AS DeniedNote, COALESCE([Appeal 
Success],[Appeal Denied]) AS AppealNote
FROM
(SELECT Claim,Notes FROM @Table2) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
MAX(Notes)
FOR Notes IN ([Denied],[Appeal Success],[Approved],[Appeal Denied])
) AS PivotTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT uc.claim,
       uc.adduser,
       MAX(CASE WHEN nc.notetype = 1 THEN nc.notes END) AS approvalnote,
       MAX(CASE WHEN nc.notetype = 2 THEN nc.notes END) AS denialnote,
       MAX(CASE WHEN nc.notetype = 3 THEN nc.notes END) AS appealnote
  FROM user_claim uc
 INNER JOIN notes_claim nc
    ON uc.claim = nc.claim
 GROUP BY uc.claim,
          uc.adduser
```

Result

```
claim   adduser approvalnote    denialnote  appealnote
1234    Catan   NULL            Denied      Appeal Success
4567    Jigsu   Approved        NULL        NULL
7890    Panama  NULL            Denied      Appeal Denied
```